# Custom Control ClientRectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm creating a UserControl which will be the base class for other controls in a GUI.

The reason for this is so I can draw a custom border around the control.

Control has a ClientRectangle property which represents the client area of a control. UserControl has this set to the same size as the Bounds of the control.

Because I'm drawing a custom border around the control I'd like to modify the ClientRectangle, however I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

After a bit of searching around I found this page:

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-drawing/769/How-do-you-increase-the-nonclient-area-to-support-a-border

Which helped a lot.

However, I had to change the check in the switch statement to:

```
....
switch (m.Msg)
{
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (m.WParam != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS csp;

....
```

Essentially there is a lot of fiddling around with windows messages and painting non-client areas. It's not perfect and doesn't prevent laying out controls into the border in the designer.